# Insert date in an excel cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to insert the current date in a cell (with standard format). When I write the shortcut "ctrl + ;" the date is written correctly in the the cell, but when I quit the cell, the value is automatically replaced with #####, I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your column is wide enough to hold the date?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have just find the problem, I didn't think that it would be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a problem of column width.